# Add custom style property to MXML Custom Component

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex3, components, mxml

I have a Custom Component that has a couple of Canvas with some background colors assigned to them. Now i have hard coded the colors, i want to move them to an external css file.

So i would like to have the css declaration like this :

```
ControlBar  
{  
  dividerRightColor: #ffffff;  
  dividerLeftColor: #f3f3f3;  
}
```

My question is if i can define custom style names like `dividerRightColor` and if so, how can i use that value inside my MXML Component? I have seen examples of using them inside Pure AS components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSS:

```
.dividerRightColor {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}


.dividerLeftColor {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

In MXML:

```
<mx:ControlBar>
    <mx:Canvas styleName="dividerLeftColor">
        …
    </mx:Canvas>

    <mx:Canvas styleName="dividerRightColor">
        …
    </mx:Canvas>
</mx:ControlBar>
```

Comment: I am using this approach as its simple and fulfills my requirements. But both are very good answers.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you need to create the style in the component; not just send the style values into the component as the other answer.

[Read this documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=skinstyle_3.html).

Basically, styles don't get defined the same way that properties get defined.  You can set any style name on the component you want.  However, the component needs to know what to do w/ the style.  To do that you need to override the styleChanged method:

```
override public function styleChanged(styleProp:String):void {

    super.styleChanged(styleProp);

    // Check to see if style changed. 
    if (styleProp=="dividerRightColor") 
    {
      // do stuff to implement the style
      dividerRight.setStyle('backgroundColor',getStyle('dividerRightColor'));
    }
}
```

A common approach is to set "styleChanged" properties and invalidate the display list and then make the appropriate style changes in the updateDisplayList() method.

To make the style available in code hinting, you'll need to add metadata, like this:

```
[Style(name="dividerRightColor")]
```

This will only be required if you wish to set the style as a property in MXML.

Comment: Will this function also work if I add this code in the script part of my MXML file?

Comment: The styleChanged method should work fine if you add it to he script part of your MXML file.  I believe the style metadata must be put inside an mx:Metadata tag.  [Probably something different in Flex 4]